# Why doesn't matrix assignment, eg; p(1) = 1, in Octave work like other programming languages?

Tags: matlab, octave

Here is the example.

This doesn't work---

```
m = size(X, 1); % Number of training examples
p = zeros(m, 1);
p = sigmoid(X * theta);   % sigmoid returns a mx1 dimensional vector
for i = 1:m
    if ( p(i) >= 0.5)
        p(i) = 1;         % overwrite whatever value in p(i)
    endif
end
```

---

The following works---

```
m = size(X, 1); % Number of training examples
p = zeros(m, 1);
sig = sigmoid(X * theta);
for i = 1:m
    if ( sig(i) >= 0.5)
        p(i) = 1;
    endif
end
```

---

First example gives float numbers rather than 1 or 0.
The goal is to store 1 in 'p' of m-rows for every entry that satisfies the condition. By programming logic, the first and second should give the same result since I am just overwriting entries that meet the if condition, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm removing the labels `machine-learning`, `neural-network`, `logistic-regresion` because they have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example does the following : "call sigmoid on X and replace all values > 0.5 with 1"

```
m = size(X, 1);
p = zeros(m, 1);
## Here you overwrite your entire p vector do the line above has no effect
p = sigmoid(X * theta);
for i = 1:m
  if ( p(i) >= 0.5)
    p(i) = 1;         % overwrite whatever value in p(i)
  endif
end
```

The easier, vectorized way would have been:

```
p = sigmoid(X * theta);
p(p>0.5) = 1;
```

Your second example initializes `p` with zeros and sets the elements to 1 if sigmoid returns > 0.5. Which would be vectorized (yes, really just one line...)

```
p = sigmoid(X * theta) >= 0.5;
```

I hope you see your logic problem now

Comment: I am actually trying to overwrite all content of p (ie; zeros) with content of sigmoid values. Regardless p before and after overwrite has the same dimension of mx1. So what does overwriting affect the for-loop? Even then, replacing each element should give you the same result as the second piece of code.

Comment: you don't overwrite "each element" of p in the for loop, only those where the condition in `if` is satisfied.

Comment: Ok. let's just say m = 5 and p = [0;0;15;20;55] (after sigmoid return). That means p(1) = 0, p(2) = 0, p(3) = 15, p(4) = 20, p(5) = 55. Now, using for loop just like above would replace each element of p,ie; p(i) , with '1' if p(i) is greater than 0.5. Now, during for-loop, elements of p(3) p(4) and p(5) will overwritten with '1' such that p = [0;0;1;1;1]. That is how I would implement in other languages like Python if it is array. Isn't it?

Comment: I see the issue with float numbers!

Comment: I just can guess that you have some basic misconception how for loops or conditionals work. Why do you think Octave wouldn't behave here like Python?

Comment: I don't have any misconception about for / if, just some careless mistakes I overlooked. You just had to tell me I forgot 'else' statement in the first example. That solved all the issues. Second thing is, before the mistake was corrected, I saw decimals in p which confused me as to why. In other languages, if you assign a number to an array index, it isn't automatically converted into some other form, it remains intact. Frankly, octave matrix and Python arrays aren't exactly the same when you do column / row manipulation (treated differently?).